# I drilled in the wrong place, how do I fill the hole?

Tags: hole, hole-repair

I have drilled in the wrong place in the wall. I want to fill and fix this wrong hole before I drill in the correct place. The reason has to do with change in plan of what shelving system is going to be installed.

The hole I drilled is actually quite deep. I am sure it goes partially through the brick under the plaster.

Besides this, there is one more thing. I used hammed to pull out a screw that was inside a plug in the wall. The screw and plug came out but it also made a massive damage to the wall. Now hole in the wall is the size of circle formed by touching the thumb with index finger, a bit more than an inch. This hole is not very deep but is quite large.

In the shop there is a mind boggling and bewildering assortment of products. Some show picture of crack, some show picture of holes, some say 2mm, some say 6mm and so on. I am totally confused what I need to buy in this case.

How are such holes supposed to be filled in? Is it important that the filler material go all the way to the full depth of the hole? The items I found in shop show picture of cracks and I am not sure if they can be used for holes like the ones I have described.

Comment: one of those days where everything goes wrong

Comment: How about a pic or two, that's worth 1000 words or more. Even without a pic, it sounds like the best bet is to pull off any broken bits of plaster then replaster over the holes. A solid brick wall should be significantly strong enough that it will survive a relatively small hole.

Comment: Sounds like you need a patch instead of a fix.  Large deep(more than an inch) holes should have some backing, but almost any patch product for the wall type should do.  Matching paint colour to hide a patch is the hard part, but behind shelving, might not matter as much.

Comment: VTC: This has been asked and answered many times already. https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/63484/
https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/76149/25178

Comment: Lots of good tutorials on youtube about patching holes.  Watch at least 10 of them and note techniques and tips that are suitable to your skills, your walls, and the tools you own.  For small holes I think this is a good one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=410OMKsUDQY

Comment: @crip659, what is the difference between a patch and a fix?

Comment: A patch is more of just a covering of a boo-boo.  A fix is trying to make it like new, filling in the hole so it is as strong.  You only need a bit in the hole, and a second bit to smooth it out.

Answer (score 3):

Any wall filler should work for small holes like I think you refer to. We call it spackle here in the US and it can be gotten at most hardware stores and paint stores. It is heavy bodied (the consistency of spreadable cheese maybe- yuck!) and is applied with a small putty knife. It can be sanded after it dries. Not sure what your wall finish is (smooth or textured) but you can approximate matching the finish with subsequent coats of this "spackle".

And yes, you are best served to completely fill the holes by pressing the material in with the putty knife.

Answer (score 1):

Brick does not mind having a hole.

However the plaster does.

Use appropriate tube filler, cut off the tip (just a bit) and insert in the hole. There are some specifically made to fill holes (longer tip).

A filler that is in a tube that can be hand squeezed, like toothpaste.

Example: DAP  DryDex 5.5-fl oz White Spackling hole filler, or similar.

Insert as deep as it goes, Squeeze till it comes out. Now even it out with spatula.

Comment: 2 questions: 1) what is "tube filler"? 2) what is the "appropriate" kind? OP will, most likely, ask, that's why he's here...

Comment: @FreeMan  A filler that is in a tube that can be hand squeezed, like toothpaste.

Comment: @FreeMan DAP  DryDex 5.5-fl oz White Spackling hole filler.

Comment: @FreeMan if satisfied, go ahead and reward me.